# AWS Lambda function using HTTP module not making any request

Tags: node.js, https, aws-lambda, nodes

I have a AWS Lambda function using Node.js 12.x. Here is my code:

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
const https = require('https');

const sheetId = 01234;

const testData = JSON.stringify({"toTop":true, "cells": [ {"columnId": 3148210723153796, "value": 'TEST'} ] });

const options = {
    hostname: 'api.website.com',
    port: 443,
    path: `/logs`,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer oefohjeoiefoijn'
    }
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

// Write data to request body
req.write(testData);
req.end();
}
```

The request is not being executed. I am not receiving any errors in Cloudwatch. The exact code (with the Handler export removed) is working fine in Node.js 12.x on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lambda function terminates before the response is received because you're not waiting for the callback to return.

You can wrap your request into a promise:

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
          // ...
          resolve();
        });

        req.on('error', (e) => {
            reject();
        });

        req.write(testData);
        req.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! It is running now. But I have a question, why is the previous version (no promises) working fine on Node.js but not Lambda?

Comment: Your lambda will only wait until the promise for your `async` function `handler` will be resolved or rejected, but not for other asynchronous operations which are in the event loop (in this case your HTTP operation). If your function gets invoked before it was deprovisioned by AWS (next invoke will resolve in a cold start), there could be the case that operations that were 'stuck' in the event loop from previous operations will be finished on the next execution of your lambda. Can't tell you why it is designed like that though :)

Comment: Interesting. I really appreciate the in-depth explanation. Thank you :)